# Swift JSON Parsing problem, cannot return proper number of cells

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I faced a problem as I cannot return number of cells from the fetchedData object.
I can print an array with data however I cannot fill out cells.
It'd be great if anybody could help me resolve this mystery :)

Here's my Model:

```
import Foundation

struct ExchangeRateModel: Codable {
  let table: String
  let no: String
  let effectiveDate: String
  let rates: [Rate]
}

struct Rate: Codable {
  let currency: String
  let code: String
  let mid: Double
}
```

and rootVC

```
import UIKit

class RootViewController: UIViewController {

  private let cellID = "cell"
  private let tabelType = ["a","b","c"]
  private let exchangeTabels = ["Tabela A", "Tabela B", "Tabela C"]
  private var currentTable = "a"
  private let urlString = "https://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/tables/"
  var fetchedData = [ExchangeRateModel]()


  private let tableView: UITableView = {
    let tabel = UITableView()
    return tabel
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureNavBar()
    configureView()
    configureTable()
    performeRequest()
    tableView.reloadData()
  }

  private func configureNavBar(){
    title = "KURSY WALUT NBP"
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Tabele", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(tabeleTapped))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: self, action: #selector(refreshTapped))
  }

  @objc private func tabeleTapped(){
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Zmień tabele kursów", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    for table in exchangeTabels {
      ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: table, style: .default, handler: changeTable))
    }
    present(ac, animated: true)
  }

  func changeTable(action: UIAlertAction){
    if action.title == exchangeTabels[0]{
      currentTable = tabelType[0]
      tableView.reloadData()
    } else if action.title == exchangeTabels[1] {
      currentTable = tabelType[1]
      tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
      currentTable = tabelType[2]
      tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }

  @objc private func refreshTapped(){
    tableView.reloadData()
  }

  private func configureView(){
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
  }

  private func configureTable(){
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.rowHeight = 50
    tableView.register(TabelTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)
  }

  private func performeRequest(){
    let urlString = "\(self.urlString)\(currentTable)"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    print("URL: \(url!)")
    guard url != nil else { return }
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
      if error == nil && data != nil {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
          let decodedData = try decoder.decode([ExchangeRateModel].self, from: data!)
          self.fetchedData = decodedData
          print(self.fetchedData)
        } catch {
          print(error)
        }
      }
    }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      dataTask.resume()
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }
}

extension RootViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(fetchedData.count)
    return fetchedData.count
  }
```

Here I'm not sure how to return those data

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! TabelTableViewCell
    cell.currencyNameLabel.text = fetchedData[indexPath.row].rates[indexPath.row].currency
    cell.currencyCodeLabel.text = fetchedData[indexPath.row].rates[indexPath.row].code
    cell.effectiveDateLabel.text = fetchedData[indexPath.row].effectiveDate
    cell.midRateLabel.text = String(fetchedData[indexPath.row].rates[indexPath.row].mid)
    return cell
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let nextVC = CurrencyViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
  }
}
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: whats the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to reload tableview after getting the value from server.

Try this code

```
private func performeRequest(){
    let urlString = "\(self.urlString)\(currentTable)"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    print("URL: \(url!)")
    guard url != nil else { return }
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
      if error == nil && data != nil {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
          let decodedData = try decoder.decode([ExchangeRateModel].self, from: data!)
          self.fetchedData = decodedData
          print(self.fetchedData)
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.tableView.reloadData()
           }
        } catch {
          print(error)
        }
      }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
  }
```

The json contains only one `ExchangeRateModel` in the array.

Seems like you want to show the rates. You need to `return fetchedData[0].rates.count` instead of `return fetchedData.count`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     if fetchedData.count > 0 {
          return fetchedData[0].rates.count
     }
     return 0
  }
```

Also you need to update `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! TabelTableViewCell
    cell.currencyNameLabel.text = fetchedData[0].rates[indexPath.row].currency
    cell.currencyCodeLabel.text = fetchedData[0].rates[indexPath.row].code
    cell.effectiveDateLabel.text = fetchedData[0].effectiveDate
    cell.midRateLabel.text = String(fetchedData[0].rates[indexPath.row].mid)
    return cell
  }
```

Comment: Great thanks, that helped with the table.
Unfortunately I'm getting only one row displayed instead of all that are fetched from api and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Would you please share the json String if possible?

Comment: As I cannot put it here due to the lack of space, I'm placing everything below.

Comment: thank you for swift response. I updated code but now in console I have such an information: Fatal error: Index out of range
2020-04-06 09:51:10.426739+0200 NBPExchangeRates[87827:4287184] Fatal error: Index out of range
(lldb)

Comment: Yes, I changed everything as you described above

Comment: @Tzebulion just update my answer in `numberOfRowsInSection` method. Please check. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You did't reload table after coming response from the api call. inside response callback where you print the array of response you have to reload tableview.

`do {
          let decodedData = try decoder.decode([ExchangeRateModel].self, from: data!)
          self.fetchedData = decodedData
          print(self.fetchedData)
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
      }
        } catch {
          print(error)
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I also added DispatchQueue and updated all other places.
See below:

```
 private func performeRequest(){
    let urlString = "\(self.urlString)\(currentTable)"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)
    print("URL: \(url!)")
    guard url != nil else { return }
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
      if error == nil && data != nil {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
          let decodedData = try decoder.decode([ExchangeRateModel].self, from: data!)
          self.fetchedData = decodedData
          print(self.fetchedData)
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
        } catch {
          print(error)
        }
      }
    }
    dataTask.resume()
  }
}
```

and also table:

```
extension RootViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print(fetchedData.count)
    return fetchedData[0].rates.count
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! TabelTableViewCell
    cell.currencyNameLabel.text = fetchedData[0].rates[indexPath.row].currency
    cell.currencyCodeLabel.text = fetchedData[0].rates[indexPath.row].code
    cell.effectiveDateLabel.text = fetchedData[0].effectiveDate
    cell.midRateLabel.text = String(fetchedData[0].rates[indexPath.row].mid)
    return cell
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let nextVC = CurrencyViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
  }
}
```

and I'm still getting this error.

Comment: This is what is displayed in console:

Fatal error: Index out of range
2020-04-06 11:07:41.810872+0200 NBPExchangeRates[1961:64368] Fatal error: Index out of range
(lldb)